# On click dissapearing message in php

Tags: javascript, php, html

I wrote a code to show the user the error message or/and the success message on different answers that he/she gives and when it clicks somewhere on the screen to dissapear that message
My problem now is if it gets success and error at the same time only the first message dissapears from the screen when the user clicks somewhere else.
I want to dissapear both messages in that case.
My code seems to work perfectly but i cant locate the error of that.

```
  <?php

if(isset($_SESSION['danger'])){ ?>
    <div id="myMsg"class ="alert alert-danger">

        <?php
            echo $_SESSION['danger'];
            unset($_SESSION['danger']);
        ?>
    </div>

<?php }
if( isset($_SESSION['success'])){ ?>
  <div id="myMsg"class ="alert alert-success">

    <?php
        echo $_SESSION['success'];
        unset($_SESSION['success']);
    ?>
</div>
<?php   } ?>

<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = function(){
  var myMsg = document.getElementById('myMsg');
  document.onclick = function(e){
    if(e.target.id !== 'myMsg'){
    myMsg.style.display = 'none';
  }
};
};
</script> 
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">timedMsg()</script>
```

Comment: All your message divs has the same id. That's not valid in HTML. All id's _must_ be unique within a document. When you fetch elements by id in JS, it will always only return the first it finds. If you want to be able to select multiple elements at once, give them a class that you select on instead, maybe the `alert` class?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson i tried and set a different id to the divs but i still have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

instead of using id, set a custom class maybe my-msg

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){
  var alerts = document.querySelectorAll('.my-msg');
  document.onclick = function(e){
    if(!e.target.classList.contains('my-msg')){
      for(alert of alerts){
          alert.style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
};
</script>
```